# Storing and Caching data memory using STL Containers vs sqlite in-memory database

Tags: c++, sqlite, stl

I'm writing a cache for a small to moderate (few thousand records) sized database. The data is stored in a non-sqlite format on disk.

C++ containers would allow type safety, while I suspect SQL database would likely have quicker and easier searching and indexing.

How do sqlite and C++ containers compare with respect to performance, ease of implementation etc?

Comment: If its only a few thousand records and it all fits in-memory, the only thing sqlite is going to buy you is the expressivity of using SQL to perform searches, and the price you pay will be their modeling and storage requirements. You will be hard pressed to beat the performance of properly-managed standard-lib containers if such a requirement does not exist.

Comment: @WhozCraig The `properly-managed` bit is what I'm worried about - I suspect that developers (myself included) will get lazy or not keep optimization in mind. I'd rather have 50% worse that optimum code is all cases rather that having to go through the code and optimize all container uses later.

Comment: Certainly something to consider, and I know all-too-well the conditions and circumstances of which you speak.